# Javascript ES6 Arrow Function

Tags: javascript, function

Why Javascript ES6 introduce arrow function ? why simple function is changed by arrow function. The arrow function in javascript cannot make the code clean and I think everyone sticks using arrow function. What is the best alternative to arrow function in javascript.

I tried arrow function but the code is not readable

Comment: Use traditional functions if you want.